# Do I need to duplicate all events for mobile vs desktop in snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I found that Snap.svg has both touchstart, touchend, mousedown, mouseup events.

So do I need to write code something like the following?

```
if (isMobile())
{
   myButton.touchstart(function(){
    console.log("mobile press");
   });
}
else
{
 myButton.mousedown(function(){
    console.log("desktop press");
   });
}
```

Or maybe (preferrably) Snap.svg has 'pressdown' and 'pressup' events to handle both mobile and desktop simultaneously?